# COM Interface pointer return null from MFC ActiveX control

Tags: dll, com, interface, mfc, activex

I am new to COM dll. I have dll's and .tld file and document which describes methods, classId exposed by dll.I tried following program using VS 2008 stand alone project and able to initialise and successfully call the methods. However the following code when I put in MFC ActiveX control project (on specific button click), its not working and crashing. When debugged found m_pInterface is null in "comip.h - Native C++ compiler COM support - COM interface pointers header".

Can someone tell me why? And what I need to add/modify in following code in order to call from MFC ActiveX project.

```
HRESULT hResult = CoInitialize(NULL);
CLSID ClassID;

if(SUCCEEDED(CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("WorldClass.AssetManager.1"), &ClassID)))
{
    IDispatch *pDispatch;
    if(SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(ClassID, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            IID_IDispatch, (void **)&pDispatch)))
     {
    //call dll methods here

     }
}
CoUnInitialize();
```

Comment: Wherever you use `SUCCEEDED` macro - it is checking returned status for being non-negative. Negative values mean error, and you need to check what exactly the error code is.

Comment: The above issue has been resolved after installing redist VS2005. Since COM dlls was developed using VS2005, it has dependency and on development machine redist VS2005 was missing. After installing redist VS2005 the above code works like charm. thanks.